# Can I use UML with dimensional modeling to design a web application?

Tags: web-applications, uml, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

I want to build an analytics dashboard and I have used dimensional modeling to design the database I wonder if it's possible to use UML diagrams to design the application. I don't think that class diagram can be used because dimensional modeling doesn't seem to be compatible with class diagram but is it possible to use other diagrams ? or is it preferable to just describe the application and functionalities without any uml diagrams.

Comment: You probably can because UML is (as the name says) universal. However, I think that there are tools out there specialized on DB modeling which can do a better job.

Comment: The U in UML does not stand for “universal”. It stands for “unified”.

Comment: Yes, and I see no reason why you can't use class diagrams for dimension modelling. This might be worth while if you want to identify the logical relationships for dimensions without getting into table definitions.

Comment: @JimL. which doesn't make it any less universal ;-)

Comment: I was commenting on “as the name says”, so that nobody “learns” something that’s wrong.

Comment: @JimL. You are right, of course. Somehow this Universal got burned in my brain sooo many years ago and it proved to be true all the time ;-)

Comment: Just trying to prevent this meme from burning into someone else's brain! 

Comment: I have downvoted this question, because it is too broad for stackoverflow. Whether to use UML to design an analytics dashboard and if so, which UML diagrams should be used, depends on many factors, e.g. personal preference. How to combine UML with dimensional modeling could be the subject of a book.

Answer (score 1):

UML comes as a standard to some level based on OOP approach but it is in no way limited to just such approach. On the contrary UML is encouraged to be used in parts as needed for specific projects. If you don't find class diagram useful but you do other parts of UML, just use those.

On the other hand you may not be interested in the specifics of classes as such but still understanding the dependencies between the objects/entities do exist regardless of the technology so I believe class diagram can come in handy anyway.

Finally it is clearly stated that UML is intended to be technology neutral. Actually at some stage of the analysis you can easily use UML before even deciding into going into specific technology. From this perspective there is nothing wrong with using UML at least at the conceptual level. It might just not be the best solution to design the technical details of the solution.

I don't have experience with dimensional databases so I can't help more how specifically could you use UML in your project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree that it may be helpful to use some uml diagrams, but after some search on the internet I found that uml diagrams for dimensional modeling is a subject of research. So I guess for now I can't really use uml, For those who want a deeper look at the subject I found these links: UML For Data Warehouse Dimensional Modeling: https://www.witpress.com/elibrary/wit-transactions-on-information-and-communication-technologies/32/14269 A UML profile for multidimensional modeling in data warehouses:https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169023X0500176X